# Pending Type When Redirect From Node + Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am sending POST request from client using JQuery and redirecting to root using node.js.
But in my developer console i am getting the status : 302 (temporarily) and type : Pending

**Client Code:**

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
            username_var:username_var,
            password_var:password_var          
        }),
    url: "/login",
    success: function(data){ 
        alert(data)       
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.name);
    }
});
```

**Server Code:**

```
if (req.method == 'POST'){
    console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("Received body data:");
        console.log(chunk.toString());
        var userLoginObject = JSON.parse(chunk);
        console.log(userLoginObject.username_var);
        console.log(userLoginObject.password_var);
        var status = {
            name: "CHATEAU DE SAINT COSME",
            year: "2009",
            grapes: "Grenache / Syrah",
            country: "France",
            region: "Southern Rhone",
            description: "The aromas of fruit and spice...",
            picture: "saint_cosme.jpg"
        };
        res.redirect("/");
        res.end();
      // //res.send(status);
      // res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "http://localhost:8000/"});
      // res.end("Test");
    });
```

Comment: firstly, your server code if block is missing a closing bracket

Comment: Added the closing bracket, (I missed when i pasted the code). Basically i want a redirect from server side. I tried the code from stack but i am getting pending type in my developer console.

Comment: Returning a 30x response + Location header will redirect the request being made, so in your case it will redirect the Ajax request, not the page the user is viewing. Is your question about how to redirect the user, or why you end up with `Pending`?

Comment: Exactly, What i read in stack says if i use 30x resposen with location then the page will be redirected. From Login.html to Home.html. I am not sure why i am getting the Pending ! . I did redirect to the home page using client side script after receiving the resposen from the serverbut if i could redirect from server that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless things have changed (over the last year or so), redirect from the server (using expressJS) will not work for a POST operation from the client.  You can redirect from the client side using something like this (essentially, when you need to redirect, send a certain message that you can check on in the callback handler for the post operation):

```
$.post('/login',function(){  //window.location to be called upon message from server
 window.location = 'page to redirect to';  //you can check for a certain message from server
});
```

In your case, it will be this part:

```
    success: function(data){ 
 window.location = 'page to redirect to';
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ali. This is the solution i put together however i am confused whether thats the right approach or is there is any better way to do it

Comment: for a POST operation, I think that is a solution that will work (you can redirect from the server for non POST calls).  This was true for me about 18 months ago.

Comment: Thats Correct Ali, I am able to redirect from a GET request with  redirect("");